# Knockout.js - How to get the sum of a property grouped by another property in an observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have accounts with charges and need to print each account name and its total charge. I couldn't figure out how to get the running total grouped by account. I could get distinct account names and get the total charge per account in two separate arrays. How can I get the sum of charges for each account (similar to SQL `GROUP BY` functionality)?

### JavaScript

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self    = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { AccountId: 1, AccountName: 'Acc1', Charge: 10 },
        { AccountId: 2, AccountName: 'Acc2', Charge: 20 },
        { AccountId: 3, AccountName: 'Acc3', Charge: 30 },
        { AccountId: 1, AccountName: 'Acc1', Charge: 10 },
        { AccountId: 1, AccountName: 'Acc1', Charge: 10 },
        { AccountId: 2, AccountName: 'Acc2', Charge: 20 },
        { AccountId: 2, AccountName: 'Acc2', Charge: 20 }
    ]);

    self.headers = [                     
        { title: 'AccountName'  },
        { title: 'AccountTotal' }
    ];                


    self.justAccounts = ko.computed(function () {
        var accounts = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.people(), function (item) {
            return item.AccountName;
        });
        return accounts.sort();
    });

    self.uniqueAccounts = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(self.justAccounts()).sort();
    });

    self.AccTotals = ko.computed(function () {
        var result = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.uniqueAccounts(), function (acc) {
            var accTotal = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.people(), function (item) {
                if (item.AccountName == acc) {
                    accTotal += item.Charge;
                }
            })
            result.push(accTotal);
        });

        return result;
    });

}
```

### Markup

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: uniqueAccounts">
    <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>                                   
</tr>
<tr data-bind="foreach: AccTotals">
    <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>                                   
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
self.accounts = ko.computed(function () {
    var acc = {}, accs = [];

    // accumulate accounts, group by name
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.people(), function (person) {
        if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(person.AccountName)) {
            acc[person.AccountName] = {
                AccountName: person.AccountName,
                AccountTotal: 0,
                PersonCount: 0
            };
            accs.push(acc[person.AccountName]);
        }
        acc[person.AccountName].PersonCount++;
        acc[person.AccountName].AccountTotal += person.Charge;
    });

    accs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.AccountName > b.AccountName;
    });

    return accs;
});
```

and

```html
<tr data-bind="foreach: accounts">
    <td data-bind="text: AccountName"></td>                                   
</tr>
<tr data-bind="foreach: accounts">
    <td data-bind="text: AccountTotal"></td>                                   
</tr>
```

or even this, if you want to utilize your `headers` array:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: headers -->
<tr data-bind="foreach: $root.accounts">
    <td data-bind="text: $data[$parent.title]"></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

---

P.S.: You shouldn't be using `dependentObservable` anymore, they're called `computed`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not able to get the rows when I put two td together. Let me know if you have clue.

Comment: <tr data-bind="foreach: accounts">
                <td data-bind="text: AccountName"></td>                                   
                <td data-bind="text: AccountTotal"></td>                                   
            </tr>

Comment: Look at the HTML this generates and think about how the `foreach` binding works. You will find what you're doing wrong.